# Facebook smaller image posts get more people reached than large image posts?

Tags: facebook

Hiall,
I manage a facebook page for a business with about 1000 followers.

I have done 2 updates over the past week and are trying to work out why my larger image posts are not seen by as many people compared to my smaller image posts? 
In theory I would have thought the larger image post would be seen by more people than the smaller image posts???

Update 1 included

1 small image post (image size is 729 x 91 pixels) 
and straight after this post after I did a second post
1 large image post (image size is 526 x 526 pixels) 
The small image post was seen by 400+ people and the large was seen by 50+ people.

A week later I do the same thing again with fresh content and get almost the same results.

Update 2 included

1 small image post (image size is 729 x 91 pixels) 
and straight after this post after I did a second post
1 large image post (image size is 526 x 526 pixels) 
The small image post was seen by 400+ people and the large was seen by 50+ people.

Does facebook limit the amount of posts that are shown up in people newsfeeds from any poster? Is that the reason why the large image is not getting as many views, or is there another reason etc? I guess next tme I'll just post the large image first and see how it goes?

Comment: It is not the size of the image that matters

Comment: Hi Wizkid also the on the small banner the text is so small is it almost illegible (unreadable), where as on the large banner it is clear and easy to read and takes up more space. Also I posted the larger image second, so that is the one people would see first. I'm thinking it's something to do with the news feed algorithms and how they work etc.